# Fluent NHibernate Create entity mapping for overlapping entities

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, entity

For eg. I have two tables in my database

NonResidentStudents - columns studentID, studentname, ModeOfTransport

ResidentStudents - columns studentID, studentname, DateOfJoiningHostel

studentID and studentName are common columns and the last column is uncommon between the two

For some reason, I cant change these tables or define a common master table and make uncommon columns in sub tables. So the table stucture is rigid.

Now when trying to create an entity and mapping for the above schema using FLUENT NHIBERNATE (only) I would like to know if I can define some sort of a common entity and common mapping for the common columns and create child entities inheriting from the common entities. In the child entity and mapping class I will have representations for the uncommon columns. Could anyone please share code of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I did this before.

Common Class

```
public class BaseMapping : ClassMap<EntityBase>{

    public BaseMapping ()
    {
        UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping ();
        // All the rest of the mapping attributes
    }
}
```

For your individual classes that will inherit from the base you do this:

```
public class DepartmentMapping : SubclassMap<Department>
{
    public DepartmentMapping ()
    {
        Abstract ();
        // Map all the unique attributes
    }
}
```

The code above will create one class based on Department and EntityBase. It will not create a table called EntityBase.